# Add to Cart Button not working Opencart

Tags: opencart2.x

I have an issue on my site (http://co2consulting.net/e_shodai/upload/) the add to cart button isn't working. I have tried in Internet Explorer, Chrome & Firefox and none work.

I did have a new theme installed but I cant see how this would affect this and when I revert back to my old template it still does not work?

I am using opencart-2.0.3.1 version.

Comment: I think, You need to again download source from OpenCart site & then again upload default OpenCart source in your store. & then check it.

Comment: problem is not solved.. localhost site , the add to cart button isn't working.. i change the theme only.. when i change the theme cart button is working...bt 1hr left add button is not working.. i face the same problem. so please help me